# Как запустить несколько файлов Python в одном терминале Ubuntu server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, telegram, сервер

Как запустить одновременно несколько файлов Python в одном терминале? Мне нужно запустить 2 Телеграм бота, а покупать под каждого отдельный хостинг не хочется. Именно на **ubuntu server**! Там можно открыть только одно окно терминала (консоли)[image: консоль на хосте]

Comment: Для запуска программ в фоновом режиме, не блокирующем окно терминала, необходимо использовать специальный инструктор «&». Поставьте этот символ в самом конце строки после указания команды, опций и входящих параметров.

Comment: tmux вам в помощ

Comment: Для тестирования, если консоль позволяет, то ALT+F1..F6, либо запустить несколько сессий терминала. Но уже готовое приложение лучше запускать как сервис.

Answer (score 3):

Ваш вопрос включает в себя два момента - запуск скрипта, при котором консоль не будет блокироваться (запуск в фоне) и отключение процесса от текущей консоли, чтобы не держать терминал открытым.

Первое - для запуска какого-либо процесса в фоне, в конец команды необходимо добавить знак `&`

т.е. для запуска двух скриптов:

```
./script1.py &
./script2.py &
```

оба скрипта теперь работают одновременно и в фоне, но при этом при закрытии консоли, процессы будут завершены. Чтобы этого избежать, после запуска скрипта, необходимо отсоединить его от текущей сессии шелла. Для этого есть команда `disown <pid>`. Узнать pid только что запущенного процесса можно из переменной `$!`. Т.о. ваш итоговый вариант запуска двух скриптов в фоне может быть таким:

```
./script1.py &
disown $!
./script2.py &
disown $!
```

Узнать что скрипт работает можно к примеру так

```
ps -aux|grep script1.py
```

И на всякий случай. Сразу встает вопрос "А как завершить фоновые процессы". Для этого нужно узнать pid процесса (команда `pidof <name>`) и послать ему сигнал завершения (команда `kill <pid>`)

```
kill `pidof script1.py`
kill `pidof script2.py`
```

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте Screen. Это консольное приложение для поддержания нескольких оконных сессий.

Для установки пропишите в терминале эти команды:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install screen
```

Answer (score 0):

Использовать `nohup`. Запускает процессы в фоновом режиме (не блокируя основное окно консоли):

```
nohup python3 /path/to/script.py >> /path/to/log.log 2>&1 &
```

После запуска будет выведен ID процесса, по которому его можно будет "убить":

```
kill ID
```

В отличии от остальных ответов, данный способ позволяет вывести логи даже после завершения сессии SSH-консоли.